# Pandas not updating CSV

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

Dataset:
https://github.com/Bene939/newsheadlinedatasets

With my program I am labeling my dataset of news headlines. It worked fine until today.
For some reason it won't write the csv file anymore. As far as I can see the data frame gets updated though.

At around 4469 rows of my csv it started to not overwrite the csv file. And then it did. And then didnt do it again until it stopped overwriting completely at row 4474. It worked fine until now and if I create a new csv it will overwrite it.

I am using Jupyter Notebook. Is there some kind of limit to this? The labeled dataset is around 300KB.

```
!pip install pandas
!pip install pathlib

import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

#takes data frame and file name & appends it to given csv
def append_df(df, file_name):
  my_file = Path(file_name)
  if my_file.exists():
    print("Appending to existing file named " + file_name)
    orig_df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
    print("Old Data Frame: ")
    print(orig_df)
    new_df = pd.concat([orig_df, df], ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates()
    print("New Data Frame: ")
    print(new_df)
    new_df.to_csv(file_name, index=False, header = True, encoding='utf-8-sig')
  else:
    print("Creating new file named" + file_name)
    news_sentiment_df.to_csv(file_name, index=False, header = True, encoding='utf-8-sig')

#takes data frame and file name & overwrites given csv 
def update_csv(df, file_name):
  print("Overwriting " + file_name)
  df.to_csv(file_name, index=False, header = True, encoding='utf-8-sig')

#shows sentence by sentence, labels it according to input and saves it in a new csv file
print("WARNING: EDITING CSV FILE WITH EXCEL MAY CORRUPT FILE\n")
file_name = "news_headlines.csv"
new_file = "news_headlines_sentiment.csv"
news_sentiment_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["news", "sentiment"])
my_file = Path(file_name)
if my_file.exists():
  df = pd.read_csv(file_name, encoding='utf-8-sig', error_bad_lines=False)
  print("Loaded " + file_name)
  for index, row in df.iterrows():
    user_input = -1
    range = [0, 1, 2]
    while user_input not in range:
      print("####################################################################")
      print(row["news"])
      try:
        user_input = int(input("Negative: 0\nNeutral: 1\nPositive: 2\n"))
      except ValueError as err:
        print("\nPlease enter an Integer!\n")
        pass

    new_element = 0
    #label sentiment according to input
    if user_input == 0:
      new_element = [row["news"], 0]
    elif user_input == 1:
      new_element = [row["news"], 1]
    elif user_input == 2:
      new_element = [row["news"], 2]
      

    #save labeled sentence to new file
    news_sentiment_df.loc[len(news_sentiment_df)] = new_element
    append_df(news_sentiment_df, new_file)

    #delete data point from original data frame
    index_name = df[df["news"] == row["news"]].index
    df.drop(index_name, inplace=True)

    #update old csv file
    update_csv(df, file_name)


else:
  print("File not Found")
```

Comment: Have you verified that the problem is not within your csv file? And may you provide the data, at least at where it begins to go wrong? A mere 300KB data causing jupyter notebook to malfunction, that sounds really really unlikely....

Comment: thank you for your reply. I added a link to the labeled and unlabeled dataset. yes it would be very weird if 300KB would cause the system to malfunction. but the dataset does not have any problems as far as i can see. it can be displayed by jupyter notebook without any problems too

Comment: The program didn't produce any error on my machine (debian 10 64-bit, anaconda python 3.7). The program entered interactive mode after reading 4474 rows. Is this the expected behavior? If not, may you explain in detail? In addition, if you received any error message may you please attach it?

Comment: yes the program doesnt produce any errors for me too but does not behave as expected: it should take my input label append it to the data frame of the labeled dataset and then overwrite the csv with the new data frame. but for some reason after taking my input it doesnt write the new csv. if you just run it without the labeled csv it will create a new one so you can see that it does work in that case and has worked till now. additionally the current row will be deleted from the unlabeled dataset. i have no idea why it suddenly stopped writing the data frame to csv

Comment: i tried making a new csv and copying the old content. same result. so i guess the csv file isnt the problem either. the problem must be the append_df function. for some reason the concat doesnt work i think

Comment: running the program locally doesnt fix the problem either

Comment: I figured out though that if I enter a value very quickly it does work. But if I just wait a bit it still doesnt work

Comment: I still cannot imagine what is the expected behavior. At which line? Which dataframe? Which labeled dataset? Which new csv? Which input? Everything still looks like a puzzle to me. Sorry I give up on this question.

Comment: it takes 2 csv: 1 with news headlines and one with news headlines + labels. The program goes through the unlabeled news headlines. I enter a value and it writes the headline + my input as a new row to the labeled dataset. the call of the function append_df does not work correctly all of the time. I think the concat does not work because the data frame that should be updated is not

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to add duplicates while using drop_duplicates function without noticing it